# Как вывести все товары у которых произвольное поле (ACF) с именем kross!

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

То есть, если у 5-ти товаров значение поля 'kross' = 123 - то показать эти товары как связанные!

Answer (score 0):

https://wp-kama.ru/function/wp_query#parametry-proizvolnyh-polej-postmeta

```
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'kross',
            'value' => '123'
        )
    )
);
```

И в WP_query все это.